# Automatically push files from Repo A to Repo B

Tags: github, github-actions

Assume I have 2 repo's A and B, Is there a way I can automatically push files from repo A (upon any push activity) to a specified folder in repo B?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a workflow with a cron job to pull repo A in repo B at the frequency you want. I set a random cron for example.

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 6 * * 1" # At 06:00 on Monday

  jobs:
    pull_upstream:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Checkout repo B
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            repository: org/repo-b
            path: main
        - name: Pull repo A into B
          run: |
            git config --global user.email "jane.doe@gmail.com"
            git config --global user.name "Jane Doe"
            git remote add upstream git@github.com:<user>/<repo-a>.git
            git fetch upstream
            git merge upstream/main
            git push origin main
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall try it out.